# Lib or tool to record and replay http invocations during tests

Tags: java, http, proxy

Can anyone advice me on a strategy/lib/tool to quickly create functional tests for a server that exposes an HTTP api against a thick client (think desktop app)?

My idea is to record http invocations between client and server in order to replay them during tests so I can test for server side effects such as "did the server create a backup of the data" etc. The server is written in Java, but the tests could/should be written using any programmatic language/tools as it needs not share libraries with the server.

So far I've experimented with the idea to proxy all requests using some tool to generate HAR files to use as basis for generating code that replays the invocations during tests.
Unfortunately the tools I've found so far does not replay the bodies in the http put's, even though they are saved in the HAR file.

It would be preferable if it was easy to alter the invocations i.e. inserting variables for authorization etc during tests.

Comment: You can capture with WireShark. Not sure about reply. Hmmm, Fiddler2 can probably do this. Also look into Postman